# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT with an array of three elements

Tags: android, json, spring, gson

I'm developing an Android 3.1 and above application.

I'm using Spring Framework 1.0.0.0RC1 for Android, and Google GSon 2.1.

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to parsing JSON.

This is **JSON** returned by **"http://192.168.1.128/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms/"**.

```
{
    "allFormsResult": [
        {
            "FormId": 1,
            "FormName": "Formulario 1"
        },
        {
            "FormId": 2,
            "FormName": "Formulario 2"
        },
        {
            "FormId": 3,
            "FormName": "Formulario 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I do everything:

```
public class FormSpringController
{
    public static List<Form> LoadAll()
    {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

        String url = "http://192.168.1.128/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms/";

        GsonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(messageConverter);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        ResponseEntity<Form[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Form[].class);
        Form[] result= responseEntity.getBody();

        return Arrays.asList(result);
    }
}
```

When I try to parse it I get the following error:

```
W/System.err(519): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**
@hotveryspicy has suggested me there is a "problem" with JSON. This is how I'm generating JSON response (C# code):

```
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public List<FormContract> allForms()
    {
        List<FormContract> list = null;
        using (var vAdmEntities = new ADMDatabase.ADMEntities())
        {
            list = new List<FormContract>();
            foreach (var form in vAdmEntities.Form)
            {
                FormContract formC = new FormContract
                {
                    FormName = form.name.Trim(),
                    FormId = form.formId
                };
                list.Add(formC);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your string starts with "`{`", which means it is an Object(json concept) and it seems that your considering it as an array, which is wrong.

EDITED:

```
{"data":
   {
    "allFormsResult": [
        {
            "FormId": 1,
            "FormName": "Formulario 1"
        },
        {
            "FormId": 2,
            "FormName": "Formulario 2"
        },
        {
            "FormId": 3,
            "FormName": "Formulario 3"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

just append a object "data", and then continue with you parsing. It is a problem of Json when it got first element as an Array "`[`".

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix that? I can modify that web service (made with C# and WCF), but I don't know how.

Comment: how do you parsing with Gson in Android?

Comment: Parsing is made by spring framework. All my code about parsing it is shown here (on LoadAll() method).

Comment: i mean to say that how you used Gson?, response is ok but problem is at parsing side

Comment: Ok. I don't have any idea about how parsing JSON on Android, so I have followed this example: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e292. I've used Spring Framework to do it all.