# Show a Dialog inside a thread that it isn't GUI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, ui-thread

I'm developing an Android 3.1 and above application.

I have added a thread to make a REST request using Spring Framework. This is my code:

```
public class FormsListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private List<Form> forms;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait.", "Loading forms...");
      getUpdates.start();
    }

    private Thread getUpdates = new Thread ()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                forms = FormSpringController.LoadAll();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //display = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    setListAdapter(new FormAdapter(FormsListActivity.this, R.layout.form_list_item, forms));

                    ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I want to show a dialog inside catch block:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    //display = e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

I've thought to set `display` variable it there is an error, and then check it inside `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`. If display has a value then show a dialog.

What do you think? Is there any better approach?

Comment: you can not update UI or display AlertDialog from normal Thread. you have to use UI threa to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this . put all code of your thread's run method inside `handleMessage(Message message)` method

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message message){
             try
             {
                 forms = FormSpringController.LoadAll();
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 setListAdapter(new FormAdapter(FormsListActivity.this, R.layout.form_list_item, forms));

                 ListView lv = getListView();
                 lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 //display = e.getLocalizedMessage();
             }

        }
    }
```

and call this inside your Thread's run method

```
handler .sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
////code for alert dialog
}
});
```

is not recommened but you can use it.  Better to go with another thread that handled all UI tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you say me where I can find some sample code about "thread that handled all UI tasks"? Thanks

Comment: because `FormSpringController.LoadAll()` is a REST GET Request (and I think it is a synchronous call). You can see `FormSpringController.LoadAll()` source code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073290/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-with-an-array-of-three-elements

Comment: If that is the then better uo use async task

Comment: Thanks, but, how can I show a dialog inside catch block? I think I can't. Thanks.

Comment: try the solution mentioned above in your catch block