# Error while parsing JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

When I am parsing JSON response using Retrofit, I am getting the below error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

My JSON response is :

```
{"Hints":"Within past week?,Within past month?,Within past year?,2000s?,1990s?,1980s?,1970s?,1960s?,Natural disaster?,Political?,Sports-related?,Movies-related?,Music-related?,Technology/Science?,Headline News?,International News?,Regional/Local News?"}
```

And Model Class:

```
public class User {

    String Hints;

    public String getHints() {
        return Hints;
    }

    public void setHints(String Hints) {
        this.Hints = Hints;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String Hints) {
        this.Hints = Hints;
    }
}
```

And the Interface is :

```
public interface UserService {
    @GET("/getCategoryHints/3")
    void getUser(Callback<List<User>> callback);
}
```

Please let me know the possible cause for this error.

Comment: Error clearly saying it should start with array `[` but it starting with object `{`. I dont know why is it so. But guessing on error type.

Comment: You have `List<User>` Your json is not array of objects.

Comment: see this answer related your Error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073290/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-with-an-array-of-three-elements

Comment: I have highlighted the error message, removed extra line breaks from the code block. I have also removed client name from title because it is not required due to presence of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using GSON,

```
public class User {

@Expose
private String Hints;

/**
* 
* @return
* The Hints
*/
public String getHints() {
return Hints;
}

/**
* 
* @param Hints
* The Hints
*/
public void setHints(String Hints) {
this.Hints = Hints;
}

}
```

and remove the `List<User>` as your response isn't a JSON array

```
public interface UserService {
    @GET("/getCategoryHints/3")
    void getUser(Callback<User> callback);
}
```